# I cant install cargo afl due to conflict libc in build

Tags: rust, build, rust-cargo, libc

i run this command for installing afl but got this error :slight_smile:
`cargo install --force afl --verbose`

```
Updating crates.io index
Installing afl v0.12.2
Compiling libc v0.2.119
Compiling semver v1.0.6
Compiling autocfg v1.1.0
Compiling memchr v2.4.1
Running rustc --crate-name build_script_build /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/libc-0.2.119/build.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="std"' -C metadata=489cdaf2d7c403f5 -C extra-filename=-489cdaf2d7c403f5 --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/build/libc-489cdaf2d7c403f5 -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --cap-lints allow
Running rustc --crate-name autocfg /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/autocfg-1.1.0/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off -C metadata=063ee82a28e313a5 -C extra-filename=-063ee82a28e313a5 --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --cap-lints allow
Running rustc --crate-name build_script_build --edition=2018 /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/semver-1.0.6/build.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="std"' -C metadata=7351912136d01cda -C extra-filename=-7351912136d01cda --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/build/semver-7351912136d01cda -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --cap-lints allow
Running rustc --crate-name build_script_build --edition=2018 /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/memchr-2.4.1/build.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="std"' -C metadata=c552c9c807dc2ab3 -C extra-filename=-c552c9c807dc2ab3 --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/build/memchr-c552c9c807dc2ab3 -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --cap-lints allow
Compiling hashbrown v0.11.2
Running rustc --crate-name hashbrown --edition=2018 /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/hashbrown-0.11.2/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no --cfg 'feature="raw"' -C metadata=7a8a69fc50ce9546 -C extra-filename=-7a8a69fc50ce9546 --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --cap-lints allow
Compiling strsim v0.10.0
Running rustc --crate-name strsim /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/strsim-0.10.0/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no -C metadata=e4a9bfc99d09f927 -C extra-filename=-e4a9bfc99d09f927 --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --cap-lints allow
Compiling bitflags v1.3.2
Running rustc --crate-name bitflags --edition=2018 /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/bitflags-1.3.2/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no --cfg 'feature="default"' -C metadata=345cb7eb64111788 -C extra-filename=-345cb7eb64111788 --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --cap-lints allow
Compiling termcolor v1.1.3
Running rustc --crate-name termcolor --edition=2018 /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/termcolor-1.1.3/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no -C metadata=78b8036dd9573a25 -C extra-filename=-78b8036dd9573a25 --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --cap-lints allow
Compiling lazy_static v1.4.0
Running rustc --crate-name lazy_static /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/lazy_static-1.4.0/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no -C metadata=5d57db6815621f76 -C extra-filename=-5d57db6815621f76 --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --cap-lints allow
Compiling textwrap v0.15.0
Running rustc --crate-name textwrap --edition=2018 /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/textwrap-0.15.0/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no -C metadata=cd7aa6e611725399 -C extra-filename=-cd7aa6e611725399 --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --cap-lints allow
Running /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/build/semver-7351912136d01cda/build-script-build
Running /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/build/semver-7351912136d01cda/build-script-build
Running /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/build/memchr-c552c9c807dc2ab3/build-script-build
Running /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/build/libc-489cdaf2d7c403f5/build-script-build
Running /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/build/libc-489cdaf2d7c403f5/build-script-build
Compiling indexmap v1.8.0
Running rustc --crate-name build_script_build --edition=2018 /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/indexmap-1.8.0/build.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off --cfg 'feature="std"' -C metadata=0e27e902e804042e -C extra-filename=-0e27e902e804042e --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/build/indexmap-0e27e902e804042e -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --extern autocfg=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/libautocfg-063ee82a28e313a5.rlib --cap-lints allow
Running rustc --crate-name semver --edition=2018 /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/semver-1.0.6/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="std"' -C metadata=19ebd8e45addb3db -C extra-filename=-19ebd8e45addb3db --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --cap-lints allow
Running rustc --crate-name semver --edition=2018 /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/semver-1.0.6/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="std"' -C metadata=1d7bba30a16d8339 -C extra-filename=-1d7bba30a16d8339 --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --cap-lints allow
Running rustc --crate-name memchr --edition=2018 /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/memchr-2.4.1/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="std"' -C metadata=a1570cb9ec84be6d -C extra-filename=-a1570cb9ec84be6d --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --cap-lints allow --cfg memchr_runtime_simd --cfg memchr_runtime_sse2 --cfg memchr_runtime_sse42 --cfg memchr_runtime_avx
Running rustc --crate-name libc /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/libc-0.2.119/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="std"' -C metadata=f7e95aa5f815e2f1 -C extra-filename=-f7e95aa5f815e2f1 --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --cap-lints allow --cfg freebsd11 --cfg libc_priv_mod_use --cfg libc_union --cfg libc_const_size_of --cfg libc_align --cfg libc_core_cvoid --cfg libc_packedN --cfg libc_cfg_target_vendor --cfg libc_non_exhaustive --cfg libc_ptr_addr_of
Running rustc --crate-name libc /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/libc-0.2.119/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="std"' -C metadata=9a10ae60f507b14c -C extra-filename=-9a10ae60f507b14c --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --cap-lints allow --cfg freebsd11 --cfg libc_priv_mod_use --cfg libc_union --cfg libc_const_size_of --cfg libc_align --cfg libc_core_cvoid --cfg libc_packedN --cfg libc_cfg_target_vendor --cfg libc_non_exhaustive --cfg libc_ptr_addr_of
Running /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/build/indexmap-0e27e902e804042e/build-script-build
Compiling rustc_version v0.4.0
Running rustc --crate-name rustc_version --edition=2018 /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rustc_version-0.4.0/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off -C metadata=292fb62eb21b074f -C extra-filename=-292fb62eb21b074f --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --extern semver=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/libsemver-19ebd8e45addb3db.rmeta --cap-lints allow
Running rustc --crate-name rustc_version --edition=2018 /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rustc_version-0.4.0/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no -C metadata=bed5d4681edaf7cb -C extra-filename=-bed5d4681edaf7cb --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --extern semver=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/libsemver-1d7bba30a16d8339.rmeta --cap-lints allow
Compiling os_str_bytes v6.0.0
Running rustc --crate-name os_str_bytes --edition=2018 /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/os_str_bytes-6.0.0/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="memchr"' --cfg 'feature="raw_os_str"' -C metadata=ce671c3094df0a42 -C extra-filename=-ce671c3094df0a42 --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --extern memchr=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/libmemchr-a1570cb9ec84be6d.rmeta --cap-lints allow
Compiling dirs-sys v0.3.6
Running rustc --crate-name dirs_sys /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/dirs-sys-0.3.6/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off -C metadata=51f6316b110756e6 -C extra-filename=-51f6316b110756e6 --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --extern libc=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/liblibc-f7e95aa5f815e2f1.rmeta --cap-lints allow
Running rustc --crate-name dirs_sys /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/dirs-sys-0.3.6/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no -C metadata=f5fdada3676bd2c3 -C extra-filename=-f5fdada3676bd2c3 --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --extern libc=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/liblibc-9a10ae60f507b14c.rmeta --cap-lints allow
Compiling atty v0.2.14
Running rustc --crate-name atty /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/atty-0.2.14/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no -C metadata=685256fd9fbea61a -C extra-filename=-685256fd9fbea61a --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --extern libc=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/liblibc-9a10ae60f507b14c.rmeta --cap-lints allow
Running rustc --crate-name indexmap --edition=2018 /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/indexmap-1.8.0/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no --cfg 'feature="std"' -C metadata=fff91d2ddab1d1a7 -C extra-filename=-fff91d2ddab1d1a7 --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --extern hashbrown=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/libhashbrown-7a8a69fc50ce9546.rmeta --cap-lints allow --cfg has_std --cfg rustc_1_51
Compiling dirs v4.0.0
Running rustc --crate-name dirs /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/dirs-4.0.0/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off -C metadata=6aff32080b5fc743 -C extra-filename=-6aff32080b5fc743 --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --extern dirs_sys=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/libdirs_sys-51f6316b110756e6.rmeta --cap-lints allow
Running rustc --crate-name dirs /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/dirs-4.0.0/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no -C metadata=a9ada6ab380a540f -C extra-filename=-a9ada6ab380a540f --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --extern dirs_sys=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/libdirs_sys-f5fdada3676bd2c3.rmeta --cap-lints allow
Compiling xdg v2.4.1
Running rustc --crate-name xdg /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/xdg-2.4.1/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off -C metadata=8c79e9ee680a82f9 -C extra-filename=-8c79e9ee680a82f9 --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --extern dirs=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/libdirs-6aff32080b5fc743.rmeta --cap-lints allow
Running rustc --crate-name xdg /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/xdg-2.4.1/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no -C metadata=56ccbb96751e96a8 -C extra-filename=-56ccbb96751e96a8 --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --extern dirs=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/libdirs-a9ada6ab380a540f.rmeta --cap-lints allow
Compiling clap v3.1.6
Running rustc --crate-name clap --edition=2018 /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/clap-3.1.6/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no --cfg 'feature="atty"' --cfg 'feature="cargo"' --cfg 'feature="color"' --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="lazy_static"' --cfg 'feature="std"' --cfg 'feature="strsim"' --cfg 'feature="suggestions"' --cfg 'feature="termcolor"' -C metadata=4476793233282858 -C extra-filename=-4476793233282858 --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --extern atty=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/libatty-685256fd9fbea61a.rmeta --extern bitflags=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/libbitflags-345cb7eb64111788.rmeta --extern indexmap=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/libindexmap-fff91d2ddab1d1a7.rmeta --extern lazy_static=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/liblazy_static-5d57db6815621f76.rmeta --extern os_str_bytes=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/libos_str_bytes-ce671c3094df0a42.rmeta --extern strsim=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/libstrsim-e4a9bfc99d09f927.rmeta --extern termcolor=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/libtermcolor-78b8036dd9573a25.rmeta --extern textwrap=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/libtextwrap-cd7aa6e611725399.rmeta --cap-lints allow
Compiling afl v0.12.2
Running rustc --crate-name build_script_build --edition=2018 /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/afl-0.12.2/build.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off -C metadata=0bee46d871bd2819 -C extra-filename=-0bee46d871bd2819 --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/build/afl-0bee46d871bd2819 -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --extern rustc_version=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/librustc_version-292fb62eb21b074f.rlib --extern xdg=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/libxdg-8c79e9ee680a82f9.rlib --cap-lints allow
Running /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/build/afl-0bee46d871bd2819/build-script-build
Running rustc --crate-name afl --edition=2018 /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/afl-0.12.2/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no -C metadata=7f4e5c9351273efb -C extra-filename=-7f4e5c9351273efb --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --extern clap=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/libclap-4476793233282858.rmeta --extern libc=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/liblibc-9a10ae60f507b14c.rmeta --extern rustc_version=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/librustc_version-bed5d4681edaf7cb.rmeta --extern xdg=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/libxdg-56ccbb96751e96a8.rmeta --cap-lints allow
error[E0460]: found possibly newer version of crate libc which xdg depends on
--> /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/afl-0.12.2/src/common.rs:3:5
|
3 | use xdg;
| ^^^
|
= note: perhaps that crate needs to be recompiled?
= note: the following crate versions were found:
crate libc: /home/kayvan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-b4424726f33da388.rlib
crate xdg: /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/libxdg-56ccbb96751e96a8.rmeta

error: failed to compile afl v0.12.2, intermediate artifacts can be found at /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30

Caused by:
could not compile afl due to previous error

Caused by:
process didn't exit successfully: rustc --crate-name afl --edition=2018 /home/kayvan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/afl-0.12.2/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no -C metadata=7f4e5c9351273efb -C extra-filename=-7f4e5c9351273efb --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps --extern clap=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/libclap-4476793233282858.rmeta --extern libc=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/liblibc-9a10ae60f507b14c.rmeta --extern rustc_version=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/librustc_version-bed5d4681edaf7cb.rmeta --extern xdg=/tmp/cargo-install2NJn30/release/deps/libxdg-56ccbb96751e96a8.rmeta --cap-lints allow (exit status: 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its done.
cargo +nightly install --force afl --verbose